# Non scalar struct array

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct

This is very complicated problem about data structures, I will try and explain it as simple as possible

I have multiple signals in a array `signals`, every element of this is a structure with multiple segments of the signal and its attribute.

Now I have another function which filters this signal and does some calculation according to the cut off frequency.

Whenever this function is called, I want to loop through all `fc`, and through all signals and through all segments. But the problem is `fc` is calculated only in a signal, so I have something like this:

```
classdef datHandle < handle
    properties
        error_norm = {};
        final_error = {};
        signals = {};
    end
    methods

        function this = addsignal(this, varargin)
            %signal segmentation is done here
        end

        function this = addfilter(this, varargin)
            for i = 1:length(this.signals)% for each signal
                this.error_norm = {};
                fn = 1/((mean(diff(this.signals{i}(1).time)))*2);
                fc = linspace(1,fn,(fn/0.5)); %calculate fc
                this.tempaddfilt(fc,i)
            end
            this.final_error = [this.final_error;this.error_norm];
        end

        function this = tempaddfilt(this,varargin)
            s = [];
            f = ltiFilter.PT1(); % initiate filter class
            fc = varargin{1}; % take fc
            i = varargin{2}; % the exact signal
            for a = 1:length(fc) % fc
                q = 0;
                w = 0;
                for k = 1:length(this.segments{i}) % segment of ith signal
                    f.fc = fc(a);
                    filt_sig = f.eval(this.segments{i}(k).signal,this.segments{i}(k).signal(1)); %signal and the initial value of the signal
                    filt_sig = filt_sig';
                    s(1,i).main(k).seg_err(a) = std((filt_sig-this.segments{i}(k).ref)); % calculate the standard diviation of the signal
                    q = q+s(1,i).main(k).seg_err(a);
                    s(1,i).main(k).fc(a) = fc(a);
                end
                s(1,i).main(i).sig_err(a) = q;
                w = w+s(1,i).main(i).sig_err(a);
            end
            s(1,1).main(1).filt_err(a) = w;
            this.error_norm = [this.error_norm s];
        end
    end
end
```

test script:

```
clear all
close all
filname = load('file');
signal1  = filname.signal;  % current value
time1 = filname.time;
signal2  = filname.signal2;  % current value
time2 = filname.time2;

f = ltiFilter.datHandle();

f.addsignal(signal1,time1,93);
f.addfilter()
```

I planned the `final_norm` to be something like this:

[image: final norm]

But my algorithm doesn't work, when I add 2nd signal. If anyone has better algorithm any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand, what is your data structure and why each signal is divided into segments? Do you have frame-based signal processing (chunk by chunk), or there is an algorithm for signal segmentation?

I think you should make more than one class with object vectorization along signals, filters and segments.